# In PHP Fatal Error will show up with error_reporting(0)

Tags: php

I had a test interview for a front-end position and the company even wanted to know my php level. 
I am not so good at php so this is why I put the question here. In a question I had a class named `ClassOne`, with the a protected method `show()`. This class was extended by `ClassTwo`. `ClassTwo` was instantiated and the show method was invoked on it.
In the top of the script I called `error_reporting(0)`.

```js
error_reporting(0);
class ClassOne {
protected function show(){}
}
class ClassTwo extends ClassOne{

}
$obj2 = new ClassTwo(); 
$obj2->show();
```

I had to say what the code will display and I said "nothing, because show is protected and error_reporting(0) will not let any error to display." Is this right?

Someone told me that this will yield a fatal error and will be displayed even with error_reporting(0). 
The test was on paper so I don't know the right answer.

Comment: why don't you test it on your system before asking? check here:-1:-https://eval.in/655112   and  2:-  https://eval.in/655114 and 3:- https://eval.in/655117

Comment: You get a `parse error syntax error, unexpected '$obj2' (T_VARIABLE)` because of the missing `;`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ghehe nice find! xD

Comment: will display nothing, acording to eval.in

Comment: That somebody was wrong and now you have a SO question with an erronous title.  It's a good idea to make sure your question title is relevant to the main bulk of your question rather than the last 2 sentences of hearsay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the classes, and protected methods, and the design. It's all misdirection.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$obj = new Anything(); 
$obj->do();
```

Are there any syntax errors? No. PHP parses the script and begins executing it. At line 2 all error reporting is turned off. At line 3 PHP attempts to instantiate the `Anything` class. The class can't be found, which causes a fatal error. Error reporting was turned off. No error is reported. Nothing to display.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$obj = new Anything(); 
foo
$obj->do();
```

Are there any syntax errors? Yes, at line 4. PHP can't parse the script, which causes a "Parse error: syntax error ...". Is error reporting enabled? Line 2 is irrelevant, the script was never executed. Loaded configurations are consulted because PHP loaded fine (e.g. php.ini settings). If error reporting is enabled then a `Parse error: syntax error` is reported. Is the error displayed? It depends on the environment and other configurations such as `display_errors`, `log_error` in a CLI SAPI. Let's assume a straight forward Apache environment with `display_errors=1`, then the error is displayed.

The error reporting setting is about reporting errors. This doesn't mean that they will be displayed. Errors might be logged and not displayed e.g. for security reasons. Nonetheless, notice that if error reporting is disabled, it doesn't matter if displaying them is enabled because there's nothing to display.

Answer (score 0):

`E_ERROR` error level (corresponding to fatal errors) is equal to 1, which means that `error_reporting(0);` suppresses these errors as well.

However `error_reporting()` function might be [disabled at all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). This might be the reason why that person thought otherwise.